# Stacks, Queues and reading math from file.. odd output

Tags: java, stack, queue, infix-notation

Hello again Stackoverflow,

I am in the process of creating an infix to postfix calculator.  the calculator must read input from a file and then use stacks and queues to create postfix notation.  i have all of my code to read the file and create the postfix notation in a queue.  the file that i am reading from contains:

> (4>3)+(3=4)+2

here is my code to put into postfix notation in a queue:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Proj1Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        readMathFile();
        q.printQueue();

    }

    public static void readMath(char c, myStack s, myQueue q) {
        if (c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9') {
            System.out.println("NUMBER"); // <--for testing.
            int o = (int)c;
            q.enqueue(o);
        } else if(c == '+' || c=='-') {
            System.out.println("+ or -");
            Object x = s.pop();
            while( !s.isEmpty() ) {
                q.enqueue(x);
                x = s.pop();
            }
        } else if(c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '!' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '&' || c == '|' || c == '=') {
            System.out.println("other operator"); // <--for testing.
            Object x = s.pop();
            char y = x.toString().charAt(0);
            while( !s.isEmpty() && (y != '\\' || y != '*') ) {
                q.enqueue(y);
                y = (Character)s.pop();
                if(y != '\\' || y != '*') {
                    q.enqueue(y);
                    s.push(x);
                }
            }
        } else if(c=='\\' || c == '*') {
            System.out.println("divide or multiply"); // <--for testing.
            Object x = s.pop();
            while( !s.isEmpty() ) {
                q.enqueue(x);
                x = s.pop();
            }
        } else if(c == ')') {
            System.out.println("close paren"); // <--for testing.
            Object x = s.pop();
            while( !s.isEmpty() && x != "(" ) {
                q.enqueue(x);
                x = s.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    public static myStack s;
    public static myQueue q;

    // the file reading code was borrowed from:
    // http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Readfilecharacterbycharacter.htm
    public static void readMathFile() {
        s = new myStack();
        q = new myQueue();
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println(file + " does not exist.");
            return;
        }
        if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) {
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            char current;
            // in this while loop is where all of the reading happens
            while (fis.available() > 0) {
                current = (char) fis.read();
                readMath(current, s, q);
            }
            if(fis.available() == 0) {
                Object x = s.pop();
                while(!x.equals("empty stack"))
                    q.enqueue(s.pop());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

after i run the code, i print the output which turns out to be:

> QUEUE:
>   52
>   51
>   51
>   52
>   50

I have no idea where 52, 51, etc are coming from. it should read "4>33=4+2+" (i think) i was wondering if anybody could identify my problem? or give me some tips on how to fix it?

Comment: Ever heard of such a tool called a debugger, Ted?

Comment: no... is there such a thing? lol

Answer (score 1):

52 51 51 52 50... are ASCII code for the characters '4', '3', '3', '4', '2' respectively.

When you are doing:

```
current = (char) fis.read();
```

you are getting the characters themselves.

Later in readMath():

```
int o = (int)c;
```

You are converting in an integer and putting it in a queue. Probably when you print the queue, it is still an integer and it comes out as the ascii code.

You can convert a digit char to the integer it represents by doing this:

```
Character.getNumericValue(c);
```

Comment: hmm.. what happened to the operators though? and how do i convert ASCII to decimal/regular?